# Selecting rows matching a time pattern in R

Tags: r, date, data.table, subset

I've been working on this dataset for a while now so I hope I can get some help. I would like to simplify my question to:

How can I select rows having the following time-stamped pattern in column `Time`: `**/**/**** **:**:00`?

Hope I was clear! I can attach a `head()` sample below:

```
> head(dataraw)
                  Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving
1: 17/06/2018 09:36:00  34.333333  19.666667  40.000000         0     150       0       35     27
2: 17/06/2018 09:37:20   9.666667   7.000000  12.333333         0     185       0        0     26
3: 17/06/2018 09:38:40   7.333333   4.000000   8.666667         0     168       0        0     11
4: 17/06/2018 09:40:00  14.000000   9.333333  17.333333         0      99      58        0     11
5: 17/06/2018 09:41:20  19.000000  13.000000  23.333333         0      37     124        0     11
6: 17/06/2018 09:42:40  23.000000  14.000000  27.000000         0       8     196        0      0
   Grooming Resting Fleeing Unknown End
1:       17       0       0      11   0
2:       23       0       0       6   0
3:       30       0       0      31   0
4:       35       0       0      37   0
5:       31       0       0      37   0
6:       17       0       0      19   0
```

Find attached a sample below:

```
> dput(dataraw[(1:280),])
structure(list(Time = c("17/06/2018 09:36:00", "17/06/2018 09:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:38:40", "17/06/2018 09:40:00", "17/06/2018 09:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:42:40", "17/06/2018 09:44:00", "17/06/2018 09:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:46:40", "17/06/2018 09:48:00", "17/06/2018 09:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:50:40", "17/06/2018 09:52:00", "17/06/2018 09:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:54:40", "17/06/2018 09:56:00", "17/06/2018 09:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 09:58:40", "17/06/2018 10:00:00", "17/06/2018 10:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:02:40", "17/06/2018 10:04:00", "17/06/2018 10:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:06:40", "17/06/2018 10:08:00", "17/06/2018 10:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:10:40", "17/06/2018 10:12:00", "17/06/2018 10:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:14:40", "17/06/2018 10:16:00", "17/06/2018 10:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:18:40", "17/06/2018 10:20:00", "17/06/2018 10:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:22:40", "17/06/2018 10:24:00", "17/06/2018 10:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:26:40", "17/06/2018 10:28:00", "17/06/2018 10:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:30:40", "17/06/2018 10:32:00", "17/06/2018 10:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:34:40", "17/06/2018 10:36:00", "17/06/2018 10:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:38:40", "17/06/2018 10:40:00", "17/06/2018 10:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:42:40", "17/06/2018 10:44:00", "17/06/2018 10:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:46:40", "17/06/2018 10:48:00", "17/06/2018 10:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:50:40", "17/06/2018 10:52:00", "17/06/2018 10:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:54:40", "17/06/2018 10:56:00", "17/06/2018 10:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 10:58:40", "17/06/2018 11:00:00", "17/06/2018 11:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:02:40", "17/06/2018 11:04:00", "17/06/2018 11:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:06:40", "17/06/2018 11:08:00", "17/06/2018 11:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:10:40", "17/06/2018 11:12:00", "17/06/2018 11:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:14:40", "17/06/2018 11:16:00", "17/06/2018 11:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:18:40", "17/06/2018 11:20:00", "17/06/2018 11:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:22:40", "17/06/2018 11:24:00", "17/06/2018 11:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:26:40", "17/06/2018 11:28:00", "17/06/2018 11:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:30:40", "17/06/2018 11:32:00", "17/06/2018 11:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:34:40", "17/06/2018 11:36:00", "17/06/2018 11:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:38:40", "17/06/2018 11:40:00", "17/06/2018 11:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:42:40", "17/06/2018 11:44:00", "17/06/2018 11:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:46:40", "17/06/2018 11:48:00", "17/06/2018 11:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:50:40", "17/06/2018 11:52:00", "17/06/2018 11:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:54:40", "17/06/2018 11:56:00", "17/06/2018 11:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 11:58:40", "17/06/2018 12:00:00", "17/06/2018 12:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:02:40", "17/06/2018 12:04:00", "17/06/2018 12:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:06:40", "17/06/2018 12:08:00", "17/06/2018 12:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:10:40", "17/06/2018 12:12:00", "17/06/2018 12:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:14:40", "17/06/2018 12:16:00", "17/06/2018 12:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:18:40", "17/06/2018 12:20:00", "17/06/2018 12:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:22:40", "17/06/2018 12:24:00", "17/06/2018 12:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:26:40", "17/06/2018 12:28:00", "17/06/2018 12:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:30:40", "17/06/2018 12:32:00", "17/06/2018 12:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:34:40", "17/06/2018 12:36:00", "17/06/2018 12:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:38:40", "17/06/2018 12:40:00", "17/06/2018 12:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:42:40", "17/06/2018 12:44:00", "17/06/2018 12:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:46:40", "17/06/2018 12:48:00", "17/06/2018 12:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:50:40", "17/06/2018 12:52:00", "17/06/2018 12:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:54:40", "17/06/2018 12:56:00", "17/06/2018 12:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 12:58:40", "17/06/2018 13:00:00", "17/06/2018 13:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:02:40", "17/06/2018 13:04:00", "17/06/2018 13:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:06:40", "17/06/2018 13:08:00", "17/06/2018 13:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:10:40", "17/06/2018 13:12:00", "17/06/2018 13:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:14:40", "17/06/2018 13:16:00", "17/06/2018 13:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:18:40", "17/06/2018 13:20:00", "17/06/2018 13:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:22:40", "17/06/2018 13:24:00", "17/06/2018 13:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:26:40", "17/06/2018 13:28:00", "17/06/2018 13:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:30:40", "17/06/2018 13:32:00", "17/06/2018 13:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:34:40", "17/06/2018 13:36:00", "17/06/2018 13:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:38:40", "17/06/2018 13:40:00", "17/06/2018 13:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:42:40", "17/06/2018 13:44:00", "17/06/2018 13:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:46:40", "17/06/2018 13:48:00", "17/06/2018 13:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:50:40", "17/06/2018 13:52:00", "17/06/2018 13:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:54:40", "17/06/2018 13:56:00", "17/06/2018 13:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 13:58:40", "17/06/2018 14:00:00", "17/06/2018 14:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:02:40", "17/06/2018 14:04:00", "17/06/2018 14:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:06:40", "17/06/2018 14:08:00", "17/06/2018 14:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:10:40", "17/06/2018 14:12:00", "17/06/2018 14:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:14:40", "17/06/2018 14:16:00", "17/06/2018 14:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:18:40", "17/06/2018 14:20:00", "17/06/2018 14:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:22:40", "17/06/2018 14:24:00", "17/06/2018 14:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:26:40", "17/06/2018 14:28:00", "17/06/2018 14:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:30:40", "17/06/2018 14:32:00", "17/06/2018 14:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:34:40", "17/06/2018 14:36:00", "17/06/2018 14:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:38:40", "17/06/2018 14:40:00", "17/06/2018 14:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:42:40", "17/06/2018 14:44:00", "17/06/2018 14:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:46:40", "17/06/2018 14:48:00", "17/06/2018 14:49:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:50:40", "17/06/2018 14:52:00", "17/06/2018 14:53:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:54:40", "17/06/2018 14:56:00", "17/06/2018 14:57:20", 
"17/06/2018 14:58:40", "17/06/2018 15:00:00", "17/06/2018 15:01:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:02:40", "17/06/2018 15:04:00", "17/06/2018 15:05:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:06:40", "17/06/2018 15:08:00", "17/06/2018 15:09:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:10:40", "17/06/2018 15:12:00", "17/06/2018 15:13:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:14:40", "17/06/2018 15:16:00", "17/06/2018 15:17:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:18:40", "17/06/2018 15:20:00", "17/06/2018 15:21:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:22:40", "17/06/2018 15:24:00", "17/06/2018 15:25:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:26:40", "17/06/2018 15:28:00", "17/06/2018 15:29:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:30:40", "17/06/2018 15:32:00", "17/06/2018 15:33:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:34:40", "17/06/2018 15:36:00", "17/06/2018 15:37:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:38:40", "17/06/2018 15:40:00", "17/06/2018 15:41:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:42:40", "17/06/2018 15:44:00", "17/06/2018 15:45:20", 
"17/06/2018 15:46:40", "17/06/2018 15:48:00"), ACTIVITY_X = c(34.33333333, 
9.666666667, 7.333333333, 14, 19, 23, 21, 21, 21.33333333, 22.66666667, 
20.66666667, 17.66666667, 19.66666667, 32.66666667, 51.33333333, 
88, 105, 101, 68.33333333, 62.33333333, 85.66666667, 98.33333333, 
105.3333333, 91, 107, 99, 92.66666667, 98, 110.6666667, 120, 
104, 110.3333333, 132, 148.6666667, 130, 110.6666667, 89.66666667, 
92, 88.66666667, 88.66666667, 90.33333333, 100, 100, 87.66666667, 
71.33333333, 67.33333333, 65.33333333, 63, 66.66666667, 68.33333333, 
67, 63.33333333, 71.66666667, 80.66666667, 95.33333333, 109.6666667, 
122.3333333, 110, 84.66666667, 59.66666667, 59, 70.66666667, 
86.66666667, 93, 95, 86, 78.66666667, 69, 73.66666667, 72.66666667, 
69.66666667, 49, 42.66666667, 43.66666667, 53.33333333, 48.33333333, 
46.33333333, 47.66666667, 54.66666667, 58, 54, 52.33333333, 56.66666667, 
58, 60.33333333, 62, 72, 83, 94, 93, 98, 82.33333333, 83, 73, 
79.66666667, 75.66666667, 63, 45.33333333, 48.33333333, 44.66666667, 
44.66666667, 32, 35.33333333, 38, 39.33333333, 42.33333333, 35, 
40.66666667, 49.66666667, 71.33333333, 80.33333333, 76.66666667, 
66.66666667, 48.66666667, 38.33333333, 46.66666667, 58, 72.33333333, 
68, 71.33333333, 65.66666667, 64.66666667, 54.33333333, 52.66666667, 
49.66666667, 57.66666667, 64.66666667, 78.66666667, 83.33333333, 
86, 83.66666667, 82.66666667, 77.33333333, 68.33333333, 73.33333333, 
76, 72, 50, 47, 50.66666667, 59, 48.33333333, 39.33333333, 35, 
35.33333333, 40, 37.66666667, 41.66666667, 40.66666667, 37.66666667, 
30.33333333, 25, 24, 24.33333333, 25.66666667, 34.33333333, 37, 
36.33333333, 31, 35.66666667, 37.33333333, 42, 37, 39.66666667, 
38, 41.66666667, 45.66666667, 40.66666667, 38.66666667, 30, 36.33333333, 
55.66666667, 60.66666667, 64.33333333, 48.66666667, 49.33333333, 
46.33333333, 45, 47.33333333, 51.33333333, 48.33333333, 40.33333333, 
32.66666667, 38.33333333, 44, 47, 49.33333333, 44.33333333, 41.66666667, 
34.33333333, 37.66666667, 37.66666667, 37.33333333, 35, 30.66666667, 
30, 34.66666667, 46.33333333, 55.66666667, 62.66666667, 98.66666667, 
118.6666667, 111, 73.33333333, 55, 54.66666667, 53, 50.66666667, 
52.33333333, 58, 55.66666667, 62.66666667, 63.33333333, 66, 60, 
54, 47, 44, 40.66666667, 46.33333333, 45.66666667, 50, 46, 45.33333333, 
44, 38, 36, 36, 40.66666667, 43, 57, 79, 80.66666667, 64, 35.33333333, 
33.33333333, 27.33333333, 35, 33, 34.66666667, 27.33333333, 21, 
29.66666667, 32.66666667, 43.33333333, 46.33333333, 54, 55, 37.66666667, 
20, 7.666666667, 14, 30.66666667, 33, 29, 17.33333333, 14.66666667, 
9.333333333, 14.66666667, 17.66666667, 24.66666667, 17, 18.33333333, 
26.33333333, 50, 80.66666667, 97.66666667, 107.6666667, 94.33333333, 
76.66666667, 64.66666667, 68.33333333, 65.33333333, 51, 30.33333333, 
24.66666667, 20.66666667, 22.33333333, 29.33333333, 46), ACTIVITY_Y = c(19.66666667, 
7, 4, 9.333333333, 13, 14, 10, 10.66666667, 12.33333333, 17.33333333, 
14.33333333, 11.66666667, 11, 25, 57.33333333, 94.66666667, 123, 
109.3333333, 76.33333333, 58, 68, 73.66666667, 75, 63, 69, 58, 
57.66666667, 70.66666667, 89, 96.66666667, 84.33333333, 92.66666667, 
111, 125.3333333, 121.6666667, 120.3333333, 115.6666667, 102.6666667, 
102.6666667, 111.6666667, 110, 104.3333333, 91, 85, 79.33333333, 
79.66666667, 76, 58.66666667, 57.33333333, 63.66666667, 79, 80, 
97.33333333, 98.33333333, 94.66666667, 89, 84.66666667, 111, 
95, 92, 70, 95.33333333, 109, 100.3333333, 80.66666667, 69, 75.33333333, 
68, 74, 64.33333333, 65.33333333, 40, 34, 32.33333333, 41, 39.66666667, 
38.33333333, 38, 40, 41.33333333, 37.66666667, 34.66666667, 49.33333333, 
56.33333333, 61, 53, 55.66666667, 79.33333333, 90.33333333, 113, 
147, 141.6666667, 128, 70.66666667, 58.33333333, 46.33333333, 
47.66666667, 41.66666667, 55.66666667, 50.33333333, 53.66666667, 
29.66666667, 34.66666667, 35.33333333, 41.33333333, 45.66666667, 
38, 48.33333333, 53, 80, 92, 97.33333333, 75.33333333, 47.66666667, 
30.66666667, 56.33333333, 67.66666667, 98, 79, 78.66666667, 62.66666667, 
69, 66.33333333, 51.33333333, 56, 90.33333333, 103, 102.6666667, 
78.33333333, 80, 81, 73, 62.33333333, 55.33333333, 61.33333333, 
64.66666667, 58.33333333, 44.33333333, 47.33333333, 52.33333333, 
68.33333333, 53, 39, 21, 22.66666667, 28.66666667, 24.66666667, 
26.33333333, 25.33333333, 23.33333333, 21.33333333, 17, 20.33333333, 
19.66666667, 20.66666667, 35.33333333, 39, 37, 21, 24.33333333, 
27.66666667, 32, 25.33333333, 27, 24.66666667, 25, 28.33333333, 
27.33333333, 31, 23, 29.33333333, 57.66666667, 61.33333333, 64, 
38, 40, 40, 38, 37.66666667, 34.66666667, 34.33333333, 31, 27, 
25.66666667, 31, 33.66666667, 38.66666667, 33, 29.66666667, 21, 
21.33333333, 21, 22.66666667, 22.66666667, 21.66666667, 20.66666667, 
22, 30.33333333, 50.66666667, 76.33333333, 141.6666667, 169, 
151, 87, 45.66666667, 38.33333333, 33.66666667, 32, 31.66666667, 
36, 32.33333333, 35.66666667, 38.66666667, 44.33333333, 46, 40.66666667, 
32, 26.66666667, 21, 30, 31, 35.66666667, 31.33333333, 28.33333333, 
22.66666667, 17, 16, 23.33333333, 31.33333333, 65, 95.33333333, 
98, 74, 37.66666667, 29, 23.66666667, 22.33333333, 34.33333333, 
39, 45.33333333, 32, 21.33333333, 26, 30.33333333, 37.33333333, 
35, 49.33333333, 56.33333333, 42.66666667, 19.33333333, 4.333333333, 
8.666666667, 22.33333333, 23.66666667, 21, 9, 6.666666667, 3.666666667, 
11.66666667, 15.33333333, 20.66666667, 17, 28.66666667, 46, 76.66666667, 
95.66666667, 108, 103.3333333, 90.33333333, 62.66666667, 48.33333333, 
52, 52, 40.33333333, 20.33333333, 22.66666667, 21.33333333, 22, 
26.66666667, 52), ACTIVITY_Z = c(40, 12.33333333, 8.666666667, 
17.33333333, 23.33333333, 27, 23, 23.33333333, 24.66666667, 28.66666667, 
25.66666667, 21.66666667, 22.66666667, 41, 77.66666667, 130, 
162.6666667, 149.3333333, 103, 85.33333333, 109.6666667, 123.3333333, 
129.6666667, 111, 127.6666667, 115, 109.6666667, 121.3333333, 
142, 154, 133.6666667, 144, 172.3333333, 194.3333333, 179.3333333, 
165, 146.6666667, 138.3333333, 136.3333333, 143.3333333, 143.6666667, 
145.6666667, 135.3333333, 122, 107, 104.6666667, 100.6666667, 
86.66666667, 88, 93.66666667, 104, 102.3333333, 121, 127.3333333, 
136, 142, 149, 160.6666667, 131, 110.3333333, 91.66666667, 119, 
139.6666667, 138.6666667, 125.6666667, 111, 109.3333333, 97, 
104.6666667, 97.66666667, 96, 63.33333333, 54.66666667, 54.33333333, 
67.33333333, 62.33333333, 60, 61, 68, 71.33333333, 65.66666667, 
62.66666667, 76, 82, 86.33333333, 82, 91, 115.3333333, 130.6666667, 
147.3333333, 179, 164.3333333, 153.6666667, 103, 100.3333333, 
89, 80, 61.66666667, 74, 67.33333333, 69.66666667, 43.66666667, 
49.66666667, 52, 57, 62.33333333, 52, 63.33333333, 73, 107.3333333, 
122.3333333, 124, 102, 69.33333333, 49.33333333, 73.33333333, 
89.33333333, 122.6666667, 105.6666667, 108, 91.33333333, 95, 
85.66666667, 74, 76, 109.6666667, 123, 132, 114.3333333, 117.6666667, 
116.6666667, 110.6666667, 99.66666667, 88.33333333, 96, 100, 
92.66666667, 67, 66.66666667, 72.66666667, 90.66666667, 72.66666667, 
57, 40.66666667, 42, 49, 45, 49.33333333, 48, 44.66666667, 37.66666667, 
31, 31.66666667, 31.33333333, 33, 50, 54.33333333, 52.66666667, 
37.66666667, 43.33333333, 46.33333333, 52.66666667, 44.66666667, 
48, 45.33333333, 48.66666667, 53.66666667, 49, 49.66666667, 38, 
46.66666667, 80.66666667, 87, 91.66666667, 62, 63.66666667, 61.33333333, 
59, 60.66666667, 62, 59.33333333, 51, 42.33333333, 46, 53.66666667, 
57.66666667, 62.66666667, 55.33333333, 51.33333333, 40.33333333, 
43.33333333, 43.33333333, 44, 42, 37.66666667, 36.33333333, 41, 
55.33333333, 76.33333333, 99.66666667, 172.6666667, 206.6666667, 
187.6666667, 114.3333333, 72, 67, 62.66666667, 60, 61.33333333, 
68.66666667, 65, 72.66666667, 75, 80, 75.66666667, 67.66666667, 
57.33333333, 52, 46, 55.33333333, 55.33333333, 61.33333333, 55.66666667, 
53.33333333, 49.66666667, 41.66666667, 39.66666667, 43.33333333, 
51.66666667, 80.66666667, 113, 133.3333333, 113.3333333, 75.33333333, 
46, 41, 35.33333333, 49.33333333, 51.33333333, 57.33333333, 42.66666667, 
30.33333333, 39.33333333, 44.66666667, 57.33333333, 58.33333333, 
74, 79.66666667, 57.66666667, 28.33333333, 9, 16.66666667, 38.33333333, 
41, 36, 19.66666667, 16, 10, 19, 23.66666667, 32.33333333, 24.33333333, 
34.66666667, 53, 91.66666667, 125.6666667, 146, 149.3333333, 
130.6666667, 99.33333333, 81, 86, 83.33333333, 65, 36.33333333, 
34, 30, 31.66666667, 39.66666667, 69.66666667), Vigilance = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 25L, 
25L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Head-up` = c(150L, 
185L, 168L, 99L, 37L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 121L, 
193L, 225L, 207L, 208L, 199L, 175L, 102L, 38L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
12L, 12L, 44L, 61L, 61L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
58L, 138L, 191L, 164L, 84L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 117L, 180L, 151L, 138L, 
75L, 63L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 121L, 201L, 190L, 110L, 30L, 2L, 16L, 
27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 121L, 195L, 234L), Grazing = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 58L, 124L, 196L, 205L, 177L, 105L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 63L, 63L, 72L, 84L, 164L, 223L, 217L, 
144L, 76L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 
23L, 18L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 28L, 54L, 54L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Browsing = c(35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Moving = c(27L, 
26L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 30L, 26L, 19L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 21L, 
18L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 9L, 
45L, 45L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 12L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 11L, 18L, 28L, 47L, 40L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), Grooming = c(17L, 23L, 30L, 35L, 31L, 17L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 17L, 10L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 
5L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
6L), Resting = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fleeing = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Unknown = c(11L, 6L, 31L, 37L, 37L, 
19L, 20L, 48L, 90L, 77L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
48L, 61L, 87L, 79L, 66L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 75L, 75L, 23L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 53L, 53L, 11L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 
11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 73L, 112L, 51L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 18L, 12L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), End = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 111L, 191L, 240L, 199L, 119L, 
39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 56L, 56L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 58L, 138L, 218L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 179L, 99L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 69L, 149L, 
229L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 199L, 
119L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 121L, 201L, 240L, 199L, 119L, 39L, 0L, 
79L, 159L, 198L, 133L, 112L, 107L, 173L, 194L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 199L, 119L, 39L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-280L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002631ef0>)
```

Comment: Only those that end in `:00`?! Could you provide your data with `dput`?!

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, those with `:00` seconds. I just updated my question with a large sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We  can use:

```
df[grep(":00$",df$Time),]
```

Results(truncated for visibility):

```
head(df[grep(":00$",df$Time),1:4])
                  Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z
1: 17/06/2018 09:36:00   34.33333  19.666667   40.00000
2: 17/06/2018 09:40:00   14.00000   9.333333   17.33333
3: 17/06/2018 09:44:00   21.00000  10.000000   23.00000
4: 17/06/2018 09:48:00   22.66667  17.333333   28.66667
5: 17/06/2018 09:52:00   19.66667  11.000000   22.66667
6: 17/06/2018 09:56:00   88.00000  94.666667  130.00000
```

Comment: As it's tagged `data.table` you could also use the `grepl` shortcut `%like%` for readability: `df[Time %like% ":00$"]`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways to do it in base R if you wanted to convert your column to date/time class. I edited it to create needless columns instead of just converting your time column to show different ways to use `POSIXt` classes. There are pros and cons to using either. From my understanding using `lt` is usually a little slower but you can access the time elements using `$` b/c it is a named list. Check out `?POSIXlt` for a better understanding of both

```
df1$Timelt <- as.POSIXlt(df1$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df1$Timect <- as.POSIXct(df1$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

df1[format(df1$Timect, "%S") == "00",]

df1[df1$Timelt$s == 00,] 
df1[format(df1$Timelt, "%S") == "00",]


head(df1[df1$Timelt$sec == 00,])

                  Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving Grooming
1  17/06/2018 09:36:00   34.33333  19.666667   40.00000         0     150       0       35     27       17
4  17/06/2018 09:40:00   14.00000   9.333333   17.33333         0      99      58        0     11       35
7  17/06/2018 09:44:00   21.00000  10.000000   23.00000         0       8     205        0      0        7
10 17/06/2018 09:48:00   22.66667  17.333333   28.66667         0       0      38        0     10        4
13 17/06/2018 09:52:00   19.66667  11.000000   22.66667         0      41       0        0      0        0
16 17/06/2018 09:56:00   88.00000  94.666667  130.00000         7     225       0        0      0        8
   Resting Fleeing Unknown End              Timelt              Timect
1        0       0      11   0 2018-06-17 09:36:00 2018-06-17 09:36:00
4        0       0      37   0 2018-06-17 09:40:00 2018-06-17 09:40:00
7        0       0      20   0 2018-06-17 09:44:00 2018-06-17 09:44:00
10       0       0      77 111 2018-06-17 09:48:00 2018-06-17 09:48:00
13       0       0       0 199 2018-06-17 09:52:00 2018-06-17 09:52:00
16       0       0       0   0 2018-06-17 09:56:00 2018-06-17 09:56:00
```